# C# - Static nested classes

Tags: c#, oop

I have two classes which I want to access from any part of Windows Forms application. How to add a couple of Participants and how to referce them?
The idea is this:

```
//add participants
Dialog.Participants.Add(new Participant { state = "" });
//modify state
Dialog.Participants[0].state = ...


public class Dialog
{
    public static string state { get; set; }
    public static List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
}

public class Participant
{
    public static string state { get; set; }
    public static List<string> actions { get; set; }
}
```

maybe there is some better way to do it?

Comment: You can allways access public classes and members from everywhere. However you´ll need a reference to an instance of them. If you want only one single instance use the singleton-pattern for this instead of relying on static classes.

Comment: Well what happens with the code you've got? And what does that have to do with the title? (I'd certainly suggest starting to follow .NET naming conventions, for one thing. And it looks like you're never creating a new `List<string>`...)

Comment: You need to create instances of the classes and make the instance global by putting variable name outside a method.  You probably also want to make the variables static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably misusing the static keyword. Static use is to have all instances of one class share the same values. Here the state of a participant would be the same for every participant.

Try just removing the static keyword from your participants and you are probably done.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [Singleton-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for this which enables you to have only *one single instance of a class per app-domain*. This way you don´t need any `static` at all, just get the single instance and call any of its members:

```
public class Dialog
{
    private readonly static _instance = new Dialog();
    public static Instance { get { return _instance; }}

    public List<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can just use this code fom *anywhere* in your program:

```
Dialog.Instance.Participants[.}.state ? ...
```

Comment: 1. What do you think are the benefits of a singleton over a static class? 2. Your singleton implementation can and should be improved. Please read Jon Skeet's [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#cctor) from C# in Depth.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the static modifier from Participant class properties. Being static will make them unrelated to the defiend instances and cannot be called like this:

```
Dialog.Participants[0].state = ...
```